Can't login to the shopify with command prompt

Hello, everyone.
recently, I'm seeking an experienced supporter.
As you can see, I checked version and installed node.js and ruby.
but can't access into shopify from command prompt.
please help me. I followed manual literally.
what exactly bother my development?

Have you tried shopify auth login (instead of just shopify login)?

yeah, still now.

Looks like the guide you followed might be out of date

no, I'm working on latest version.

Your question says "I followed manual literally" - can you share a link to the manual in question?

https://prnt.sc/8Be5KrE1XpWD (https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/getting-started/create)[Link]

You will be logged in autommatically, use commands:
for the app: "shopify app dev"
for the theme: "shopify theme dev"
